# Linux Bulk file renaming at specific position

Tags: rename

I want to rename all the files in the directory at specific position.

Original File sample Names:

```
neif11_fastcredit_20190629101333.txt
neif11_fastcredit_20190629101334.txt
neif11_fastcredit_20190629101335.txt
neif11_fastcredit_20190629101336.txt
neif11_fastcredit_20190629101337.txt
```

I want to rename it like:

```
neif11_fastcredit_20191129061333.txt
neif11_fastcredit_20191129061334.txt
neif11_fastcredit_20191129061335.txt
neif11_fastcredit_20191129061336.txt
neif11_fastcredit_20191129061337.txt
```

File name Understanding:

`neif11_fastcredit_2019` should remain as is the next part is month and date **[MMDD]**`0629` which I want to update to `1129` as today's date and last part is **HHMMSS** which also remain unchanged.

Need help as I am new to Linux.

Comment: What distribution are you working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have `rename` available, you can try the following (Bash) loop which uses `sed`:

```
user@host$ for FILE in *.txt; do NEWNAME=$(sed 's/_20190629/_20191129/' <<< "$FILE"); mv "$FILE" "$NEWNAME"; done
```

Note that this requires Bash. If you have another shell, you will have to resort to something like

```
user@host$ for FILE in *.txt; do NEWNAME=$(echo "$FILE" | sed 's/_20190629/_20191129/'); mv "$FILE" "$NEWNAME"; done
```

Also note that this assumes the filenames are "reasonably well-behaved", so special characters (not part of your example) may cause this to fail.

Comment: this is what i was looking for 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With [Larry Wall's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727288/12574) (`rename` (Debian, Ubuntu) or `prename` (RHEL/CentOS)):

```
rename -n s/_20190629/_20191129/ neif11_fastcredit_20190629*.txt
```

`-n` is just the "dry run" switch. Remove or replace with `-v` for actual use.

Answer (score 0):

Using `mv` and a loop:

```
for f in neif11_fastcredit_20190629*.txt; do
  mv "$f" "neif11_fastcredit_201911${f##*_201906}"
done
```

The `${f##*_201906}` part removes the longest matching prefix `neif11_fastcredit_201906` from each filename and 
leaves the `DDHHMMSS.txt` part as the new filename's suffix.