# Rename files with timestamp in filename in Synology

Tags: synology

A large number of file have been "renamed" with a timestamp in the file name. I cannot find a way to mass rename them. I was thinking of using a mass rename like "Bulk Rename Utility" and using the regex command, however I cannot create a command

The bad filename is: `[130bpm] salsaish (2020_11_04 13_32_49 UTC).wav` the file should be: `[130bpm] salsaish.wav`

so the string that has be be removed is: `(2020_11_04 13_32_49 UTC)`. However these strings may change depending on the time it was renamed, also file may contain special characters.

Is there a way to rename them all?

Comment: "_I cannot create a command_" - what have you tried? When happened (or didn't happen)?

Comment: i dont know much about regex, but the only language i know is PHP so i tried there, too many examples to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the long delay, but here is the code ive used in PHP:

```
<?php
function getDirContents($dir, &$results = array()) {
    $files = scandir($dir);

    foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
        $path = realpath($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
        if (!is_dir($path)) {
            $results[] = $path;
        } else if ($value != "." && $value != "..") {
            getDirContents($path, $results);
            $results[] = $path;
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

$dir = getDirContents('./DBM5000');

echo '<table equalcells="1">';

foreach($dir as $file)
{
    
    $good_file = preg_replace("/ \([^)]+\)/","", $file);    
    
    $isfile = is_file($good_file);
    
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$file.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$good_file.'</td>';
    
    if(pathinfo($good_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))
    {
        echo '<td>FILE</td>';
        
        rename($file, $good_file);
        
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<td>DIRECTORY</td>';
    }
    
    echo '</tr>';   
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

On my `Synology`, there's no `Perl` nor `rename` by default. By security concern of *attack surface*, you shouldn't add any `Perl` on your device. There's an addon, but you can use pure `sh` that is the default shell (`sh` is linked to `bash`):

```
for i in *.wav; do echo mv -- "$i" "${i% (*}.wav"; done
```

or *substitution* in *parameter expansion*:

```
for i in *.wav; do echo mv -- "$i" "${i// (*)/}"; done
```

This use shell *parameter expansion*
See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 and "Parameter Expansion" in man bash. Also see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

```
% (*
```

means remove right part of `[[:space:]](*` as a `glob`. It's not a *regex*.

Remove `echo` when the output looks satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl implementation of `rename` program (there is another
program called `rename` which is a part of `util-linux` package):

```
$ perl-rename  -n 's, \(.+?\),,' *
[130bpm] salsaish (2020_11_04 13_32_49 UTC).wav -> [130bpm] salsaish.wav
```

It will remove the first occurrence of  whitespace followed by parenthesis and everything
between them in a non-greedy manner. Check if the new name is what you
want and remove `-n` to really perform renaming.

Comment: To guide you with Perl's rename: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727288/12574

Comment: @GillesQuenot posting a link to your answer on every question or answer that mentions perl rename is, at the very least, verging on spam. IMO, it's way beyond "verging" and definitely crossed over to spam territory - you've posted the exact same comment to three of my (ancient) answers so far.

Comment: I add context, explanations, required command to install for a bunch of OS. If you feel it annyoning, don't read